# how to make .setAttribute command CSP compliant

Tags: angular, content-security-policy

I recently had to add CSP meta tags into my application which is causing an error specifically on the .setAttribute command

How can I write the following snippets to be CSP compliant. (I've heard i can use .style but how would i write it with these types of lines)

```
nextEletxt.setAttribute('tabindex','0');
crntTarget.firstElementChild.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true')
targetElem.setAttribute('id", refID);
```

how can i rewrite these to be CSP compliant(no inline styles)